# Copy and Paste Selected Cell onto entire row until Column above is empty

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am trying to find a way to copy an active Cell in row 5 and paste the value across that cell until row 4 is empty. I have multiple sheet names and need this done for all the sheet names.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    Dim c2 As Integer
    c2 = 2
    LastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(4, c2).Value)
        If .Cells(1, c2).Value = MonthSel And .Cells(4, c2).Value = WkSel Then
            .Cells(5, c2).Value = RControl
            .Cells(5, c2).copy
            If .Cells(5, c2).Value <> "" Then
                c2 = c2 + 1
                .Cells(5, c2).Paste
            End If
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

A [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz9Vw.png) of the data I am using.

[How to results should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo4ue.png)

How to results should look like row 5 should be completely filled in with the latest value from row 5

Comment: In _"... row 5 and paste the value across that cell until row 4 is empty..."_ do you really want to say _"cell"_?

Comment: I want to use a value in row 5 and paste is across the entire row 5 until row 4 is empty

Comment: What is your source cell? is it the selected cell?

Comment: My source cell is (5,6) for this week but it will change to (5,7) next week and I would need the range to start at (5,7) this week and paste until the end then next week is will be (5,7) copy the cell and paste (5,8) until the end

Comment: What is RControl ?

Comment: RControl is the name of the value that I want to paste but I can also use row 5 column for the answer as well

Comment: Ok so it should always copy the last value (most to the right) in the row to the empty cells?

Comment: Yes, I need it to use the latest number from row 5 and copy to the rest of the row.

Answer (score 0):

From what I think I understood from your explanation, I guess this is what you want.

```
   Dim LastColumn As Integer
   Dim c2 As Integer
   Dim SourceCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
        'get last used column in row 4, ALTHOUGH THIS IS NOT NEEDED IN THIS CODE
        LastColumn = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'loop through rest of the row
        c2 = 2
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(4, c2).Value)
            If .Cells(1, c2).Value = MonthSel And .Cells(4, c2).Value = WkSel Then
                Set SourceCell = .Cells(5, c2)
            End If
            If .Cells(5, c2).Value = "" Then
                'Set the source cell for filling up empty column
                .Cells(5, c2).Value2 = SourceCell.Value2
            End If
            c2 = c2 + 1
        Loop
    End With
```

Comment: I need to ensure that the paste will not disrupt the data that is before the range. I have information in row 5 columns 1-5 and need that information to stay the same but the columns with information will change every week, so next week the columns that need to stay the same will be row 5 columns 1-6

Comment: This code does not copy and paste the cell into the rest of the row

Comment: Try it now, i have removed the RControl line that I think was messing things up.

Comment: The code still does not paste the value into the rest of the row

Comment: Did you remove the test variables from the beginning of the function I pasted? (I removed them now). I tested here and it does exactly what I presume you are asking for, including the copying of the values to the rest of the row.

Comment: The code still did not work maybe you are misunderstanding what I want.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  I need the code to take the last value added in row 5, it would be any column based on the month and week, and paste that value until the end of row 5, when row 4 is empty.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an image of the desired result so we can clarify.

Comment: I have added the desired results above in the original post

Comment: were you able to figure out a solution?